# How do I query DataFrame by the value of struct?

Tags: apache-spark

There is a DataFrame of such schema:

```
a.printSchema()
root
 |-- fieldA: long (nullable = false)
 |-- fieldB: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string(nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
```

I want to query by the value of _2 of fieldB.

I know if I want to query by the value of fieldA, `a.where("fieldA = 1234").show()`. But I don't know how I query by the value inside struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the *struct* element with `field.subfield`, for your case:

```
a.where("fieldB._2 = 123")
```

---

*Example*:

```scala
val df = Seq((1L, ("a", 2L)), (2L, ("b", 3L))).toDF("A", "B")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: bigint, B: struct<_1: string, _2: bigint>]

df.printSchema
root
 |-- A: long (nullable = false)
 |-- B: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)


df.where("B._2 = 3").show   
+---+-----+
|  A|    B|
+---+-----+
|  2|[b,3]|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you! I really want it.